# UINavigationBar and UINavigationItem but no title

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I've got a UITabController. One of the tabs is a UINavigationController. Pushing and popping the navigation stack works just fine. Every UIViewController has his own NIB with just the UIView hooked up. But unfortunately I only get a title displayed for the root navigation controller!

Usually when creating a UIViewController in a NIB you have a title attribute that you can set. But in this case the view controller **is the NIB file owner**. And in IB there is no way to set the title.

What I **can** do is to set the title in initWithNib and then it shows up.

```
if (self = [super initWithNibName: @"MyViewController" bundle:nil]) {
    self.title = @"test";
}
```

But I want to define the title in IB.

I am a bit lost here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently their is no way to set the title of the UIViewController in this scenario. Too bad.

Comment: I, like you, believe that this _SHOULD_ be possible, and I'd really like to figure out how.  You wouldn't happen to have figured it out in the 1.5yrs since?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed all possible in IB.

You need to load up the NIB file with the UITabController in it.  Then, set the **View Mode** (set of 3 icons at top left) to the middle option.  This shows all the components as a nested tree.

Then select the View Controller in question, and bring up the *Attributes Inspector*.  There you will see that you can change the title.

Have included a screenshot so you can see what I mean...

[alt text http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/1875/screenshot20090903at120.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/1875/screenshot20090903at120.png)

Comment: Indeed. And that's how I set the title of the **root* controller. The question is about the other controllers that get pushed on top. Up until now I only know how to change their title in code as IB does not expose the title attribute on the file owner.

Open up e.g. the "Completed" NIB. That's where it gets interesting for me.

Comment: The UITabController in your example is the *root* controller.  The Navigation controller essentially is the same object as different view pass underneath it, which is why if you want to set a title for subviews you need to do so in code.  You don't have to call it in the init method however - just self.title=@"test" will do it in any of the UIViewController delegate methods.

Comment: The navigation controller manages view controllers (not subviews - not  directly at least). I was referring to the root view controller that is handled by the navigation controller. When a view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack the title of the view controller is displayed. As the NIB creates the view controller instance, it should be possible to set the title in IB. Up until now I don't see a way of doing that. THAT is the problem.